# Multiplying a floor function to a number

Tags: discrete-mathematics, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Is it correct to write: 
$\cfrac{\left\lfloor{\cfrac{\pi y^2}{3\sqrt{3}x^2}}\right\rfloor}{n} \times\sqrt{3}x =\left\lfloor\cfrac{\pi y^2}{3xn}\right\rfloor$ ?

Comment: Note that x, n and y are positive integers. when could this be true?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not correct.

For $x,y$ such that $\left\lfloor\frac{\pi y^2}{3\sqrt 3 x^2}\right\rfloor\not=0$, the LHS is irrational and the RHS is rational.

**Added** :

> when could this be true?

We need $$\left\lfloor\frac{\pi y^2}{3\sqrt 3 x^2}\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor\frac{\pi y^2}{3xn}\right\rfloor=0,$$
i.e.
$$0\le \frac{\pi y^2}{3\sqrt 3 x^2}\lt 1\ \ \ \text{and}\ \ \ 0\le \frac{\pi y^2}{3xn}\lt 1,$$
i.e.
$$\pi y^2\lt 3\sqrt 3x^2\ \ \ \text{and}\ \ \ \pi y^2\lt 3xn.$$

Comment: so this means that I can not simplifying the left hand side any more?

Comment: @BenBost: I think you cannot. At least what you did is not correct. Also, see what I added.